# Dividing a square into N smaller squares and finding center coordinates of the N smaller squares

Tags: python, for-loop, numpy, sorting

I have a square that has dimensions 10x10 and I want to divide it into 25 smaller squares with dimensions 2x2 so in the end I will have a 5x5 array.What I also want to do is find the center coordinates of each of the new squares. I have written the following code as a starting point, and it gives me the coordinates of the centers of the squares of the x(0) and y(0) coordinates. I have experimented with nesting, but that gave me y values that were to high. I know I need to keep one variable fixed and iterate the other in terms of it. I am just unsure as how to link them. If any one can help out or point to some documentation that will help with finding the off diagonal elements it would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

```
def Cell_centers():
 dx = 2
 dy = 2             #length of cell side
 N = 5              #number of cells
 Xc = zeros(N)      #array creation
 Yc = zeros(N)             
 x1=0
 y1=0

 for i in range(N):       #for loops to define cell centers
   Xc[i] = dx/2 +x1                  
   x1+=dx                   #increments x1 positions by dx
 for j in range(N):
   Yc[j] = dy/2 +y1
   y1+=dy

 centers = np.array((Xc, Yc), dtype=float)    
return(centers)
```

For example if we had a square that was 2 per side and divided it into four squares of length 1 per side what I would want is some thing like this

```
 [(.5 ,1.5),(1.5,1.5)]
 [(.5,.5)  ,(.5 ,1.5)]
```

I don't know if this is correct Python that's why I am here to learn

Comment: It's not clear to me what the code is doing. What do you mean by "25 smaller squares" and "off diagonal elements"?

Comment: @Steve I edited for calcification

Comment: It sounds like you want to start with 100 numbers (10x10), and end up with 25 (5x5).  So you do you want to condense each set of 4 into a single number?

Comment: @tom the dimensions are 10by10 for example side a is 10 meters and side b is 10 meters. What I want to do is then divide the 10by10 square into smaller squares and find the centers of those smaller squares.In my example the smaller squares would have dimensions 2metersby2meters..I edited my original question to better reflect this

Comment: @Surfcast23: The code you have posted isn't syntactically correct Python. Could you fix it? Also what are "off diagonal" elements and "x(0) and y(0) coordinates" in the context of the parent square? Also your code is doing these calculations in integer. Is that really what you want? Despite your edits, this is a very confusingly presented question.

Comment: @Surfcast: I still don't know what you mean.  Try to explain it in terms of operations on elements of the array: you want to start with four floats (exactly which ones?), do something with them, and get a single other thing.  What, exactly, is that other thing? (Explanations that involve an interpretation that none of us knows where somehow these number represent "meters" and have a "center" aren't going to be useful unless you explain this interpretation.)

Comment: @Tom Think of it geometrically you have a square of dimensions 10x10 and you want to divide it in to smaller squares, and then find their centers. I want to create an array that will contain the centers of the small squares.

Comment: For questions like this it's really helpful if you can give the expected output, even if it means calculating the expected output by hand for a small example.

Comment: @Bago ok I will edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want (i updated it to return one array)?

```
import numpy as np
dx = 2.
dy = 2.
N = 5
centers = np.mgrid[dx/2:N*dx:dx, dy/2:N*dy:dy]
```

The result is:

```
>>> centers.shape
(2, 5, 5)
>>> centers
array([[[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.],
        [ 5.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  5.],
        [ 7.,  7.,  7.,  7.,  7.],
        [ 9.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.]],

       [[ 1.,  3.,  5.,  7.,  9.],
        [ 1.,  3.,  5.,  7.,  9.],
        [ 1.,  3.,  5.,  7.,  9.],
        [ 1.,  3.,  5.,  7.,  9.],
        [ 1.,  3.,  5.,  7.,  9.]]])
```

Update: You can use rollaxis if you want the coordinates to be along the last dimenssion.

```
>>> centers = np.rollaxis(centers, 0, centers.ndim)
>>> centers.shape
(5, 5, 2)
>>> centers
array([[[ 1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  3.],
        [ 1.,  5.],
        [ 1.,  7.],
        [ 1.,  9.]],

       [[ 3.,  1.],
        [ 3.,  3.],
        [ 3.,  5.],
        [ 3.,  7.],
        [ 3.,  9.]],

       [[ 5.,  1.],
        [ 5.,  3.],
        [ 5.,  5.],
        [ 5.,  7.],
        [ 5.,  9.]],

       [[ 7.,  1.],
        [ 7.,  3.],
        [ 7.,  5.],
        [ 7.,  7.],
        [ 7.,  9.]],

       [[ 9.,  1.],
        [ 9.,  3.],
        [ 9.,  5.],
        [ 9.,  7.],
        [ 9.,  9.]]])
```

Comment: Thank you for the help Bago. What I need is one array that has the x and y coordinates of the square centers

Comment: mgrid returns one array, I split it into two because I didn't read your question carefully enough, I've updated my answer to show how to keep it as one array.

Comment: I am keep getting this error when I try the code. `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    centers = np.mgrid[dx/2:N*dx:dx,dy/2*N:dy:dy]
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\index_tricks.py", line 166, in __getitem__
    nn = _nx.indices(size, typ)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 1511, in indices
    res = empty((N,)+dimensions, dtype=dtype)
ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed'`,    I don't see where the negitive dimensions are comming from

Comment: Notice, `dy/2*N:dy:dy`. If you want [9,7, ...] use `dy*N:dy/2:-dy`. If you want [1,3, ...] use `dy/2:N*dy:dy`

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been staring at the code for awhile, but did not catch that typo

Comment: Wow that rool axis function is cool. thank you. There is so much to learn about numpy and scipy

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the `diagonal` method?

```
In [1]: x = scipy.randn(5,5)

In [2]: x
Out[2]: 
array([[ 0.90077481,  0.33192388, -0.16153472, -0.78663912, -2.45735516],
       [ 0.51063641,  0.01209047, -0.39667355, -0.9603519 , -0.19263007],
       [-0.73422795, -0.45595695, -0.8915272 ,  0.20074704, -0.78286524],
       [ 0.53628315,  0.93238853, -1.16648829,  1.26122884, -0.70490362],
       [ 0.31389001, -1.48574572,  2.16641639, -0.67982623, -0.59455518]])

In [3]: x.diagonal(offset=2)
Out[3]: array([-0.16153472, -0.9603519 , -0.78286524])

In [4]: x.diagonal(offset=-3)
Out[4]: array([ 0.53628315, -1.48574572])
```

Comment: I have the diagonal elements what I need are the off diagonal ones

Comment: sorry id not interpret my output properly and  asked the wrong question

Comment: @Surfcast23: That's exactly what Steve gave you - look carefully at the output of `x.diagonal(offset=N)`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you have asked correctly, it seems like you just want something like this (implemented using numpy arrays):

```
import numpy as np

n=5
dx=2.
dy=dx

x=(dx/2.)+dx*np.arange(0,n).reshape((n,1))
y=(dy/2.)+dy*np.arange(0,n).reshape((1,n))

xcoords=np.kron(np.ones_like(x.T),x)
ycoords=np.kron(y,np.ones_like(y.T))
```

Here `x` and `y` contain what I think you are referring to as the "diagonal entries", ie. each unique x coordinate and y coordinate, calculated assuming that the "upper left" of the square is at `(0,0)`. The complete array of x and y coordinates, which I think might be the union of the "off diagonal entries" with the "diagonal entries" you mention, can then be conveniently calculated using the [Kronecker product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product). This gives a pair of 5x5 arrays, one holding the x coordindates of all the centres, the other holding the corresponding y coordinates:

```
In [77]: print xcoords
[[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 3.  3.  3.  3.  3.]
 [ 5.  5.  5.  5.  5.]
 [ 7.  7.  7.  7.  7.]
 [ 9.  9.  9.  9.  9.]]

In [78]: print ycoords
[[ 1.  3.  5.  7.  9.]
 [ 1.  3.  5.  7.  9.]
 [ 1.  3.  5.  7.  9.]
 [ 1.  3.  5.  7.  9.]
 [ 1.  3.  5.  7.  9.]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did not know about the Kron function thats pretty cool. What I actually need is one array that contains the x and y coordinates of the centers of the small squares

Comment: Those values are the x and y coordinates of the centres of each small square, relative to a fixed position on the "parent" square. How do you want the coordinates stored? As a tuple? As another dimension in the array?

Comment: How would one store the data as a tuple?